# Пишу рисовалку в QT. При рисовании любым цветом после одиночного нажатия лкм появляется чёрная точка

Tags: c++, qt

Если зажать ЛКМ и провести мышью, то получится линия, как и должно быть.
Это сам проект: https://vk.com/doc66577607_445871169
Это фрагмент кода с самим рисованием:

```
void paintScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        addEllipse(event->scenePos().x() - brushSize,
                   event->scenePos().y() - brushSize,
                   (brushSize*2),
                   (brushSize*2),
                   pen,
                   brush);
        previousPoint = event->scenePos();
    }
}

void paintScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        addLine(previousPoint.x(),
                previousPoint.y(),
                event->scenePos().x(),
                event->scenePos().y(),
                QPen(color,brushSize*2,Qt::SolidLine,Qt::RoundCap));
        previousPoint = event->scenePos();
    }
}
```

UPD: разобрался. В функции changeColor не задавал цвета кисти и пера. Спасибо.

[image: Скрин рисовалки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вызове `addEllipse` Вы используете `pen` и/или `brush` черного цвета.

Зачем Вы вообще в `mousePressEvent` что-то рисуете?

> Там цвет задан другой.

Где - там? Для линии Вы каждый раз создаете новый pen с цветом `color`. Делайте то же самое в вызове `addEllipse`, и точка будет голубая:

```
addEllipse(event->scenePos().x() - brushSize,
           event->scenePos().y() - brushSize,
           (brushSize*2),
           (brushSize*2),
           QPen(color,brushSize*2,Qt::SolidLine,Qt::RoundCap),
           brush);
```

И при чем здесь `paintEvent`? Речь идет о рисовании как реакции на движение мыши.

Comment: Для рисования существует `paintEvent`.

Comment: Там цвет задан другой. Если бы чёрный был, то и линия получалась бы чёрной.

Comment: А насчёт paintEvent спасибо.

Comment: В конструкторе paintScene: https://puu.sh/w0z0V/62aaed644f.png. Там задаётся цвет по умолчанию. Потом его можно изменять через paintScene::changeColor. Но какой ни задай по умолчанию и на какой ни измени, точки всё равно чёрные получаются

Comment: @scarletchaos - это Вы мне? Я продолжаю настаивать на своем ответе.

Comment: @Igor Вы абсолютно правы. Я разобрался. Обновил вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: @scarletchaos - Рад был помочь. Успехов.